# Product Supplier Sales (relational) database

Tags: database

I've got the following information to store:

SalesChannel F --- ( Price D ) --- Product A --- (Price X) --- Supplier V

SalesChannel G --- ( Price E ) --- Product A --- (Price Y) --- Supplier W

I first tried it with commerce and variations. But I can't setup the price information on one relationship.

Then I tried the Relation module which can do this but when displaying it, I'll get duplicates (product A 4 times and then the combinations).

Entity Relation won't help as well since I can't store the price information there (it's either at the product or at the supplier for instance).

The last shot was EVA and trying to attach a view to the products but it seems as if it won't work together with Relation so I can't use this as well (or did I just fail to find appropriate documentation?).

What can I do here? Any ideas?
I'd not like to simply add several supplier fields and price fields to the product since I'd break up the structure. :-S

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: After working on this for more than 5 days I finally found an answer/combination how to do it. I wrote a small tutorial on drupal.org about it: [drupal.org/node/2070631](https://drupal.org/node/2070631)